# Add new polygon below everything in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google.Map object with a set of polygons and polylines **already** being displayed on that.

I want to add a **new** google.maps.Polygon object that should be displayed **below** all elements (more or less like a "background" polygon).

I tried to add it with an absurd low zIndex value (-999999), but it still is displayed **above** all other elements.

This is what I have done so far:

```
            whiteBackground = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: [ {lat:40.1, lng:-97.1},
                        {lat:40.1, lng:-89.8},
                        {lat:44.5, lng:-89.8},
                        {lat:44.5, lng:-97.1} ],
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 1.5,
                fillOpacity: 1.0, 
                zIndex: -999999
            });

            // add to map and to list
            whiteBackground.setMap(my_map);
```

Is there a way to force new polygon **whiteBackground** to have the **smallest** zIndex value in the Google.Map in which it is going to be add?

Or there is an way to **iterate over** all current elements in a Google.Map object?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.   What are you setting the zIndex to for the other polygons?

Comment: I don't know if an zIndex is being set to other polygons (they are being generated by another code that is minified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you set the `zIndex` properties of all the polygons.

[proof of concept fiddle (moves smaller polygon above/below larger polygon on click of the button)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bqpomas7/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle and a small polygon that starts above it, toggles above/below by clicking the button (large polygon has zIndex=0; small polygon is +/-1.

var map;
var infoWindow;
var poly2;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 24.886,
      lng: -70.268
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
  var triangleCoords = [{
    lat: 25.774,
    lng: -80.190
  }, {
    lat: 18.466,
    lng: -66.118
  }, {
    lat: 32.321,
    lng: -64.757
  }];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    zIndex: 0
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

  var poly2Coords = [{
    lat: 26.78484736105119,
    lng: -72.24609375
  }, {
    lat: 27.059125784374068,
    lng: -68.8623046875
  }, {
    lat: 23.926013339487024,
    lng: -71.806640625
  }];

  poly2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: poly2Coords,
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    zIndex: 1
  });
  poly2.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="if (poly2.get('zIndex') > 0) poly2.setOptions({zIndex:-1}); else poly2.setOptions({zIndex:1});" />
<div id="map"></div>
```